# Try/Catch Fails When Trying to Extract EntityValidationErrors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation, edmx

I'm experiencing a problem with my program where I cannot save to the DB. I receive "Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details." I went online and found some articles about applying a Try/Catch around "SaveChanges()". This project is in MVC. The project works locally without a issue but when I push it live that is when I receive the error message.

[image: EntityValidationErrors]

Controller

```
//
    // GET: /Account/LogOff

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
            // get user information
            var user = Membership.GetUser();
            var userId = (int)user.ProviderUserKey;
            var userProfile = db.UserProfiles.Where(up => up.UserId == userId).Single();

            // used to display notifications, last login date is set when the user logs off
            var profile = db.UserProfiles.Where(up => up.UserId == userId).Single();
            profile.LastLoginDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2);
            db.Entry(profile).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                // doing my logic here
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.
          PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }

            }

            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("LogOn", "Account"); // return user to login screen
    }
```

[image: Debugger]

Comment: have you tried stepping through the code and debugging it as well as inspecting all of the values before it hit's the `db.SaveChanges()` Method

Comment: Set a breakpoint inside your catch block and look at `InnerException`. It'll tell you which fields/constraints are being violated.

Comment: Entity framework converts DateTime fields to DateTime2 and is most likely failing on your LastLoginDate. As mentioned by @PoweredByOrange your inner exception will show you the field in question.

Comment: Guys, but the IIS is complaining about an unhandled excteption that the code is actually handling, what do you think about that?

Comment: @r1verside The exception is most likely occuring before the try/catch, probably where the entity state is being set to modified so it's never making it to the catch block.

Comment: @StephenBrickner I see it now thanks.

Comment: Thank you all for responding, I have added a screenshot of the debugger. InnerException is displaying null. Please keep in mind this error only happens on the live website. Locally it works fine.

Comment: @Kane Expand "System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException" and look at its "EntityValidationErrors" field, as it's noted in the message.

Comment: it seems related to data. Are you sure there exists entry in the UserProfiles table for the particular user? Or if there is any change in the database structure related to this which might be missing in live database

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the picture. It appears that the error is about a null-able field "AddressId". Im not sure why the try/catch didn't display the message within the browser, but it was found within the debugger under "EntityValidationErrors".